# How to get notified when each time bluetooth device is paired with any devices and when it device finds any paired devices get notification?

Tags: android, bluetooth, notifications, broadcastreceiver

When device gets paired to any device i should get a notification and also if it finds any paired device aroud i should get notified . 
How to achieve this using Broadcast reciever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment i understand that you want to show if there is a nearby paired bluetooth device after bluetooth is connected..

so first after your `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` you need to start scan for paired Bluetooth devices and display them in a list. In the context of a mobile device, a Bluetooth device can either be:

1)unknown

2)paired

3)connected

It is important to know the difference between a paired and a connected Bluetooth device. Paired devices are aware of each other’s existence and share a link key, which can be used to authenticate, resulting in a connection. Devices are automatically paired once an encrypted connection is established.

Bluetooth devices are represented by the BluetoothDevice object. A list of paired devices can be obtained by invoking the getBondedDevices() method.

In your activity class

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (!BTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBT, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH);
        }
        Log.d("DEVICELIST", "Super called for DeviceListFragment onCreate\n");
        deviceItemList = new ArrayList<DeviceItem>();

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        }
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
        DeviceItem newDevice= new DeviceItem(device.getName(),device.getAddress(),"false");
        deviceItemList.add(newDevice);
    }
}
```

then create a new clsss DevicelistFragment to make a BroadcastReceiver and override the onReceive() method. The onReceive() method is invoked whenever a Bluetooth device is found.

```
    public class DeviceListFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deviceitem_list, container, false);
    ToggleButton scan = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.scan);
    ...
    scan.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            if (isChecked) {
                mAdapter.clear();
                getActivity().registerReceiver(bReciever, filter);
                bTAdapter.startDiscovery();
            } else {
                getActivity().unregisterReceiver(bReciever);
                bTAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            }
        }
    });
}
    ...
    private final BroadcastReceiver bReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Create a new device item
                DeviceItem newDevice = new DeviceItem(device.getName(), device.getAddress(), "false");
                // Add it to our adapter
                mAdapter.add(newDevice);
            }
        }
    };
    }
```

For full project see https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-BluetoothScannerFinishedProject

Also see: http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/how-to-programmatically-scan-or-discover-android-bluetooth-device/

Comment: i have a receiver already and my function works on connected right now like   ' case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED:' but after connected it need to check whether it has got any paired device around if it has got trigger some service. So my question is how ll we find there is nearby paired devices?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this snippet and handle the 
 Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
   // If there are paired devices 
   if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
   // Loop through paired devices 
   for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
   // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView 

   mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());

   //or handle here with notification.....
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can get notified when a new device is connected using Broadcast receiver


BroadcastReceiver btReceive=new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override 
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

      if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
       //the device is found 
     } 
   } 
};
```

Comment: i want to be notified when i have paired device nearby and also when newly pairing happens ,not when connected.